# Can I send a message to a D2L-internal email address?

Tags: desire2learn

Can D2L-internal email addresses get used from the outside? Can we send messages to those addresses using regular SMTP or Valence Learning Framework API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Valence Learning Framework APIs currently do not currently provide calls to interact with the D2L Learning Environment's internal email system.

Currently, the Desire2Learn Learning Environment can be configured to support 'full email', meaning that once configured like that you can connect it to other mail gateways and the D2L-internal email addresses for users are then addressable by outside services: D2L LE's deployed for 'full email' use an IIS SMTP service for mail-transfer, and so any other service connecting externally must be able to interact with such a service.

Notice that the Desire2Learn LE system may not enforce uniqueness on user email addresses; if connecting an LE configured for full email to the outside world, it's important to take this into account and verify that each LE user needing to connect to external email does, in fact, have a unique email address.